# Is there a way in Java to validate against XSD without SAX?

Tags: xml, validation, schema, sax

I'm looking at the wikipedia article about [SAX (Simple API for XML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML#Drawbacks) and I'm a little puzzled by this drawback of SAX parsing: (which conspicuously lacks a citation)

> Virtually any kind of XML validation requires access to the document in full.

I'm finding that hard to believe - for example the [javax.xml.validation.Validator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html) object throws SAX exceptions all over the place.

Is there a way to validate against an XSD in Java without using a SAX parser? If not, can you validate an XML document in Java without using a SAX parser - perhaps using something other than XSD?

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe everything you read in Wikipedia. It goes on to say that to validate IDREFS you (obviously) need to maintain the set of all IDs in the document. That doesn't mean the whole document needs to be in memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Virtually any kind of XML validation requires access to the document
>   in full.

The essence of SAX is that the interaction between the caller and the SAX library is based upon callbacks being given control when parsing events occur.  (In contrast, the essence of DOM-based parsing is that a complete representation of the document is built in memory, and the caller may then examine it using DOM library calls.)

Validating parsers such as the SAX-based ones you note in Java are ok taking on the burden of retaining state necessary to validate XML against a schema.  **The Wikipedia statement you quote is indeed somewhat confusing in this context.**  To understand its intent, imagine that you, as an application programmer, have additional tests to perform that require more state than is presented to each callback.  (It may not be the "document in full" but it likely will be more than is presented in a single SAX callback.)  Yes, validating SAX parser work, but they have to retain additional state to perform validation.  You as an application programmer also may have to retain additional state to apply your additional application-level tests, and *it is the extra work of maintaining this state the Wikipedia author intends to convey with the quoted statement*.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have a false contradiction in your question. Consider this citation you quote:

> Virtually any kind of XML validation requires access to the document in full.

You say:

> I'm finding that hard to believe...

My reading is: you doubt that you need to access to the document in full -> you think it must be possible to validate without the full document in the memory.

And then you ask:

> Is there a way to validate against an XSD in Java without using a SAX parser?

Either these are two unrelated things or I fail to see the contradiction. How is *validate ... without using a SAX parser* related to *validate without the full document in the memory*? SAX parsers are often used for low-level XML parsing, the full DOM document is then built based on SAX events. I don't see the point avoiding the SAX parser, why should you?

---

I guess, what you're really asking is, if what the Wikipedia article says is true, if you *really* need the whole document in the memory.

There are two aspects here: theoretical and practical.

Theoretically I'd say that most cases don't actually require the whole document in the memory. Most things can be validated with state machines (or something similar) and validation of literals.

I think (but not 100% sure) that there may also be cases when you'll need to keep the whole (or almost the whole document) in the memory. For instance, with XSD 1.1. alternatives I can imagine a case where the validity of the first N-1 sub-element dependes on the last Nth sub-element. You may need to keep all N in the memory.

Or this case with `ID`/`IDREF`. I agree with Michael Kay, it actually suffices to only keep the ids, but these ids may make up (almost) the whole document in a marginal case.

Practicaly I guess it's just much easier to work on the document in memory rather than validate a stream of SAX or StAX events.

Comment: The false contradiction stems from the mess of a wikipedia article: the article is about SAX, and that phrase is taken from a section titled "Drawbacks". The way I see it, the article is implying that all validation requires the document in full, but SAX doesn't handle the document in full so therefore SAX is an ineffective tool for validation. However, this is contradicted by it's widespread use for XSD validation - which is the contradiction I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Widespread use of SAX for XSD validation? Really? Any source for this? SAX is normally just used for low-mid level XML parsing. Then some document model is built and validated. I never heard of SAX-only XSD validator.

Comment: It's been two years, but at the time I was working with some XSD stuff and kept finding myself looking at SAX.. And from the question - "for example the [javax.xml.validation.Validator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html) object throws SAX exceptions all over the place."

Comment: Although it looks like I screwed up that `javax.xml.validation.Validator` hyperlink in the question.